# Variadic function not compiling

Tags: objective-c, gcc, variadic-functions

I am attempting to implement a variadic function in Objective-C and have set up a method as follows

```
- (void)method:(id)o, ...
{
    int c = 1;
    va_list list;
    va_start(list, o);
    while (va_arg(list, id))
        c++;
    va_end(list);
}
```

To me, this code appears as though it should work fine. However, when I compile it with gcc, I receive the following error

```
error: expected expression before ‘id’
```

Thinking that perhaps my attempt to use `id` was causing the problem, I swapped out `id` for `void *`; however, I experienced the same error (with `void *` taking the place of `id` in the error message). What is causing me to experience this error?

*Edit*

The code compiles using the clang compiler, but I need to be able to use gcc. Is this a bug in gcc? - [submitted to GCC as a bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66367)

Comment: I don't think you can compile objective-c with gcc.

Comment: @user3386109 [you can](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Objective-C.html) as long as you link to `lobjc`.

Comment: I just checked it and it compiles for me (but I use LLVM).

Comment: It looks pretty good and similar to i. e. `+stringWithFormat:`. Only to check this: Did your editor change `...` (three dots) to `…` (horizontal ellipse)?

Comment: Beside this: Show the code above of the method definition. Likely you missed a `}`, so you are inside another method's body and the `-` is interpreted as minus. (Or simply re-indent the whole code.)

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad Thank you for the advice. The three dots were not replaced by my editor (vim), and I don't believe I missed a closing brace only because the code successfully compiles using clang. I'm beginning to feel as though this is some sort of bug in GCC.

Comment: Yes, seems to be a bug. But `+stringWithFormat:` compiles with gcc, too, and has the same structure.